# How to instantiate a generic type object in C#?

Tags: c#

I have class like this:

```
public ClassA<T> where T : class{
       ...
}
```

Now I need to to create an object of ClassA in the constructor of ClassB:

```
public ClassB{
   public ClassA<?> objA;
   public ClassB(string TypeInfo){
       objA = new ClassA<?>(); // Suppose TypeInfo = 'ClassC', and the '?'
                               // Should be derived from TypeInfo
   }
   ...
}
```

I don't know what to replace '?' for, since the type can only be known at runtime... any ideas?

Comment: Note: I think `ClassA` needs to declare `where T : class, new()` if you want to use the default constructor. Also, @ArturMustafin is mistaken.

Comment: I want the 'TypeInfo' to be a string representation of an object type.

Comment: I'm correct, because there is no reason to use generics for the types, not known at compile time, because generics is used only for the KNOWN types, which means you can always make a substitution of a generic parameter with a type. The only matching type in this situation is `object` type

Comment: The only way to use a type not known at compile time is resolve the type at run time, make the `ClassB` generic, and use ILGeberator() for the generic ClassB to instantiate of construction of generic `ClassA` that at the run-time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closest to determining and creating the generic type at runtime that you'll probably get (using a string that represents the type name) is instantiating it like this.

```
public class ClassB
{
    public ClassB(string typeInfo)
    {
        var typeOfT = Type.GetType(typeInfo);
        var type = typeof(ClassA<>).MakeGenericType(typeOfT);
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

Exposing that directly through a public field will not be doable unless you mark your field as dynamic, because otherwise it will need that generic type information up front.

```
public dynamic objA;
```

Also, the string that represents the type must be qualified enough so that it can be located without ambiguity by `Type.GetType()`. For example, `SomeNamespace.ClassC` instead of `ClassC`.

Comment: Nice code. Although this can't solve the class definition problem, creating a generic type is a neat trick.

Answer (score 0):

use `object o = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);`

this came from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

**edit**

we use it in extension methods like;

```
public static object DefaultValue(this Type targetType) { return targetType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(targetType) : null; }
```

It's not a huge stretch to make it work with generics

Comment: You will fall into my soultion because of use `object` type

Answer (score 0):

Since objA is part of the definition of ClassB, ClassB will have to have to have a type parameter if ClassA has a type parameter, i.e.

```
public ClassB<T>
{
   public ClassA<T> objA
   ...
}
```

If the type of objA is not known at compile time it will have to be of type `Object` or a non-generic base or interface. There's no middle ground.

Comment: The goal is to use the 'TypeInfo' as a source of type information.

Comment: @baboonWorksFine - of course it's possible to construct type definitions dynamically - that's how the C# compiler works! But you are tying to go beyond the limits of C# class definition syntax

Answer (score -1):

There is no reason to use generics for the types not known at compile time, because generics is used only for the KNOWN types, which means you can always make a substitution of a generic parameter with a type.

The only matching type in the questioned situation is `object` type which is a base class for the all object types, and is always known to the compiler.

```
public ClassB{ 
   public ClassA<object> objA; 
   public ClassB(string TypeInfo){ 
       objA = new ClassA<object>();
   } 
   ... 
}
```

About your question...

The only way to use a type not known at compile time is resolve the type at run time, make the ClassB generic, and use ILGenerator() for the generic class A to instantiate of construction of that class at the run-time.

```
public ClassB<T>{ 
   public ClassA<T> objA; 
   public ClassB(){ 
       objA = new ClassA<T>();
   } 
   ... 
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't having a ClassA that's of type object defeat the purpose of using generics?

Comment: The question itself is incorrect. There is no reason to use generics for types, being resloved at runtime

Comment: Removed my downvote now that you actually explained your answer. Others will not always understand your point if you only provide code.

Comment: @Artur - Well, yes.  The question itself didn't make much sense to me, but I figured maybe there was some nuance the OP was aware of (or constrained by) that I didn't know about.